# Why is my simple tkinter animation lagging?

Tags: python, multithreading, animation, tkinter, python-multithreading

I was experimenting with tkinter module and wanted to spawn 2 witches going down. So I checked some documentation about threading in python and implemented it. I was surprised by the fact that it was pretty laggy for such a simple program.

Any suggestions why? What I did wrong? Have I missed anything important?

```
import tkinter
from threading import Thread
from random import randint
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=1000,height=500)
canvas.pack()

class Witch:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.tag = "witch-%d" % id(self)
        self.tags = ("witch", self.tag)
        self.draw_witch(self.x, self.y)

    def draw_witch(self, x, y):
        canvas.create_oval(x,y-20,x+20,y, tags=self.tags)
        canvas.create_rectangle(x,y,x+20,y+40, tags=self.tags)
        canvas.create_line(x+40,y+20,x-20,y+20, tags=self.tags)
        for i in range(-4,4):
            canvas.create_line(x-40,y+20+i*5,x-20,y+20, tags=self.tags)
    
    def move(self, speed):
        canvas.move(self.tag, speed, speed)


def landing(x, y):
    entity = Witch(x, y)
    speed = randint(1,10)
    while canvas.coords(entity.tag)[2]+40 < 1000 and canvas.coords(entity.tag)[3]+40 < 500:
        entity.move(speed)
        canvas.after(10)
        canvas.update()

for _ in range(2):
    t = Thread(target=landing, args=(randint(50, 400), randint(50, 200)))
    t.start()

canvas.mainloop()
```

Comment: Tkinter really doesn't like multiple threads, so that's likely the issue. The other thing to check is the fps to make sure the program is running fast enough that our eyes will see a smooth movement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use threading if there is no process that would requier it. The after method works just fine.

```
import tkinter
from random import randint


canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=1000,height=500)
canvas.pack()

class Witch:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.tag = "witch-%d" % id(self)
        self.tags = ("witch", self.tag)
        self.draw_witch(self.x, self.y)

    def draw_witch(self, x, y):
        canvas.create_oval(x,y-20,x+20,y, tags=self.tags)
        canvas.create_rectangle(x,y,x+20,y+40, tags=self.tags)
        canvas.create_line(x+40,y+20,x-20,y+20, tags=self.tags)
        for i in range(-4,4):
            canvas.create_line(x-40,y+20+i*5,x-20,y+20, tags=self.tags)
    
    def move(self, speed):
        canvas.move(self.tag, speed, speed)


def landing(x, y):
    entity = Witch(x, y)
    speed = randint(1,10)
    animate(entity,speed)
def animate(entity,speed):
    if canvas.coords(entity.tag)[2]+40 < 1000 and canvas.coords(entity.tag)[3]+40 < 500:
        entity.move(speed)
        canvas.after(10,animate,entity,speed)

landing(randint(50, 400), randint(50, 200))
landing(randint(50, 400), randint(50, 200))

canvas.mainloop()
```

Comment: `lambda` is not required, use `canvas.after(10, animate, entity)`.

Comment: There's no need to call `update_idletasks`. That happens implicitly once the function returns and the mainloop is allowed to continue.